# bash: django-admin: command not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

recent days I uninstall python and everything because i had some OS problem so i fix it. i delete all cash and everything and install Python again. after i install Django but when i want to starptoject getting no command found django-admin..

but Django is installed because when I'm going with shell I'm getting this message.

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
3.0.4
```

but after I want star project getting this error

```
Ketis-iMac:~ ketiaslanishvili$ Django-admin startproject test
bash: django-admin: command not found
Ketis-iMac:~ ketiaslanishvili$
```

Django is install in python 3.8

[image]

Comment: before reinstalling python and django. i was able to staproject without virtualenv. but now i even cant creat virtualenv to

Comment: whot do you get if you type following commands?
`type -a python` and `type -a pip` and `pip freeze | grep -i djang`

Comment: hello i get this

Ketis-iMac:~ ketiaslanishvili$ type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python
Ketis-iMac:~ ketiaslanishvili$ type -a python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Ketis-iMac:~ ketiaslanishvili$ type -a pip
bash: type: pip: not found
Ketis-iMac:~ ketiaslanishvili$ type -a pip3
pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3

Comment: and what about `pip freeze | grep -i djang`

Comment: I propose you add the output of my above commands to your question, as omments may be deleted lateron and as this is esential infor for helping to debug.

In your screenshot you do not show the full path of the directory site-packages.

also in general it is better to just provide text instead of images like.

the command you type and the output you get:

Please try 

`ls -ld /usr/local/bin/python3/lib/python*/site-packages/requests/*`